# using android.support.design library in intellij IDEA Ultimate edition

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-library

i am using IntelliJ IDEA 15 Ultimate edition to develop an non-gradle android project. To support libraries i copy required .jars into libs folder and then add them as dependency to my main module. Google play services, appCompatv7, supportv4 etc. This my project structure

[image: all required .jars in libs folder]

Since i want to use coordinate layout, i have to use android.support.design library. As usual, i copied .jar from [sdk]/extras/android/support/design/libs folder. But when i use coodrinate layout (or even tabLayout) in my layout xml file, i get rendering errors like this:

[image]

when i press "clear cache", i get error saying that R$attr is not found

[image]

I have being banging my head for more than 7-8 hours, searching google and stack exchange, but all solutions are targeted towards Android Studio and gradle based projects.

My Project Structure:
[image]

SDK tools installed:

[image]

What i have tried:

1. changing app theme and version in preview window
2. import android.support.design as module into my project like this
   project structure -> modules -> + -> import module -> sdk/.../support/design. After import, i also ticked "library module". Project structure after import:

[image]

**All i want is to use android.support.design library in non-gradle project**.

I can create a gradle android project on IntelliJ but i am trying my best to avoid gradle because i am more comfortable with a non-gradle project.

I am so frustrated now, that i can't think of what i am missing or doing wrong (i bet i am). I think R.class for design library is not being generated or something less is missing somewhere. Ahhh!

Any help regarding this issue of mine will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want Gradle?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable using it (i know its aweome though). Plus, since i need database support for my project (which only IntellI Ulitmate can provide), using Android Studio is out of question. Creating gradle android project on IntelliJ is not same as on AS, and is a bit quirky. I am in a real fix between IntellIJ (for DB support) and AS (for better gradle support). I can skip gradle but i cannot skip database support for my project.

Comment: I use Intellij for my Android Gradle projects. Works fine. Android Studio is a fork of Intellij. I haven't found a reason to pay money for Intellij because MySQLWorkbench, for example, is my database tool

Comment: If you are a student (which i am), you can get IntellJ Ultimate for free for one year.

Comment: Graduated last year. My point is that, you might have to bite the bullet and switch to Gradle because there are tools that exist that invalidate your reasons not to. All you have to do is add the Gradle plugin into Intellij, which the Android Studio team contributes to anyways, so saying "Android Studio has better Gradle support" doesn't make sense because it's the same Intellij plugin

Comment: i have gradle plugin installed. But gradle implementations for creating android gradle project on intellj and creating android project on AS are different. For e.g. create an gradle android project in intellij and you still have specify SDK after yout project has been created which is not the case in AS.

Comment: AS does actually ask, but the dialog is different. It asks which version of Android you want to target and downloads the correct SDK for you. In Intellij, you have to manually open the SDK Manager to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Support Library contains more than just Java code. It also contains XML and image resources. These cannot be packaged in the JAR alone. If you insist on not using Gradle, you need to configure the Android Support Library as a module within your IntelliJ IDEA project. One way to do this is to use an AAR file instead of a JAR file. I don't know the details since I just use Gradle. It imports all the resources seemlessly. This is a very good reason to port your project to Gradle.

**Update:**

Since you have the `appcompat` library as a module already, you do not need any of the support library JAR files. This assumes that the `appcompat` module is configured correctly, of course.

Comment: I tried every way possible (1. .jar only, 2. module only, 3. .jar+module), out which the current (.jar+module works). for eg. I can use AppcompatActivity without any issues. Problem is using android.support.design.CoordinateLayout file located in support.design library in my layout xml. Thanks for your time btw.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the .jar file needs to be in the module, the resource files should also be included too. The `[sdk]/extras/android/support/design` directory also contains a `res` directory, an `AndroidManifest.xml` and an empty `src` directory. Copy all those into your design module.

Answer (score 0):

add

`<option name="LIBRARY_PROJECT" value="true" />`

in design.iml of design module

[design module .iml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULdbM.png)